# setting exact bit number for binary output in java

Tags: binary, bit, binary-data

Hello I was wondering how to set the number of bits for a number in java. Eg( integer 2, but i want it to be a 8 bit binary number so 00000010). I have used Integer.toBinaryString but that only prints it out as 10. Thanks in advance

Comment: leading 0's are implicit, therefore not actually stored. if you want to display them, then run your string through a formatting function to pad out the "missing" digits.

Comment: Are you trying to set something or print something? These are completely different things because you set things to values and you print representations and values and representations are entirely different. (For example, "ten" and "10" are the same value but different representations.)

Comment: It was thanks @Kaushal28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.out.format()` instead of using `System.out.println()` for this purpose. Here you can specify your desired format, in which you want to print your `Integer` or `Float` or any other data type. Try the following code:

```
int x = 2;
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
System.out.format("%08d",Integer.parseInt(binary));
```

In above code, mark the last line. We want to print `Integer`, so we used `%d` and we wanted 8 `0`'s before that Integer `x` so we used `08`. Thus the format becomes: `%08d`. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more information about formatting.